# Are big-list questions accepted?

Tags: feature-request

Are big-list questions accepted? And to which degree? If so then please make such tag.

<sup>This question is inspired by [this one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17414/prophets-and-their-miracles).</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, big list questions are almost universally a bad fit for the SE Q&A format. They would be more suitable on some Wiki somewhere as reference material but they are inherently too broad to be questions.

Also, the sort of tag you describe would be what we call a "meta tag" in the sense that it categorizes the kind of question format rather than the subject matter and area of expertise which is what tags are supposed to categorise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: yeah, i agree with @Cateb. So my personal opinion is that: the probability of giving response will be decrease by big-list questions, since it will take plenty of time to answer, So rationally most of the users don't try to answer them.